# SQL map one value col to other value in same column

Tags: sql

I've these data :

table of possible combinations between Id and Code :

| Id | Code |
| --- | --- |
| A | 184 |
| A | 2394 |
| A | XAE48R585 |
| A | 23450403 |
| A | 140 |
| A | GDAL50000 |
| B | 45654 |
| B | 3524 |
| B | CJA3454224 |
| B | LLSZ00087 |
| B | 540 |

In one other table i have for one id its first code. In this example for id A i've the code XAE48R585 and for id B i've the code CJA3454224.

Referential table :

| Id | code1 |
| --- | --- |
| A | XAE48R585 |
| B | CJA3454224 |

But one Id have a second code that match with the first code. For the id A his second code is 140 and for id B it's 540. The global rule is that for a second code is on 3 digit and end by 0 for each Id.
And this is the case for several Id. So i would like to create a mapping like this

Mapping table:

| code1 | code2 |
| --- | --- |
| XAE48R585 | 140 |
| CJA3454224 | 540 |

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?

Comment: Hello Tim, i work on Google Bigquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its easy to in sql using mysql self join.

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1 T1, table1 T2 WHERE condition;
```